# Type mismatch in slick query

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, slick, frm

I'm new to Scala. I'm getting type errors when I try do following. WHy my findByUUID method is wrong?

```scala
case class User (token: String, email: String) {
}

class Users(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "USERS") {

  def email = column[String]("EMAIL", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def token = column[String]("TOKEN")

  def * =  (token, email) <> (User.tupled, User.unapply)

}

object UsersManager {
  def users = TableQuery[Users]

  def findByUUID(token: String) = Option[User] {
    DatabaseConfig.db.withSession { implicit session =>
      users.filter(_.token === token).firstOption
    }
  }
}
```

Here is what I get from console:

```
[error]  found   : Option[models.Users#TableElementType]
[error]  required: models.User
[error]  users.filter(_.token === token).firstOption
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a small typo:

```
def findByUUID(token: String) = Option[User] {
```

Should be (look at where the `=` sign is):

```
def findByUUID(token: String): Option[User] = {
```

Comment: You're great, thanks! Not that I spent an hour or two on this :/